# Gostaria de entender como esse código funciona

Tags: javascript

Esse código retorna todos os números primos até o especificado no limite. Mas eu fico muito em dúvida do motivo de "if (cont% divisor == 0)" já que na primeira iteração do for não deveria ser os mesmos números? então não deveria retornar false para tudo já que sempre vai dar 0 ou sempre pode dar diferente de 0? Estou realmente confuso.

```
function exibirprimos(limite){
  for(let cont = 2; cont <= limite; cont++){
    if(primo(cont)) console.log(cont)
  }
}

function primo(cont){
  for(let divisor = 2; divisor < cont ; divisor++){
    if (cont % divisor == 0) return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: Como assim *já que na primeira iteração do for não deveria ser os mesmos números?*. Se o número é primo significa que ele não possui divisores naturais menores que ele além do número 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que Os números primos são os números naturais que podem ser divididos por apenas dois fatores: o número um e ele mesmo. número primo é divisível por ele próprio e zero não pode ser dividido por zero:
Exemplo:

(o número 7 é primo ??? )

7 % 1 = 0  :: resultado zero
7 % 2 = 1
7 % 3 = 1
7 % 4 = 3
7 % 5 = 2
7 % 6 = 1
7 % 7 = 0 :: resultado zero
Só é dividido por 1 e por ele mesmo.

Em javascript, usando uma function e como parametro indicando um numero a ser indicado se é ou não primo ficaria assim.

```
var auxiliar =0; //armazena o resultado para comparação

function entrada_numero(numero){


    for(let i=1 ; i <= numero; i++){//inicia a partir do numero 1 até a quantidade indicada pelo parâmetro
        var calculo_numeros_primo =  (numero % i); //divide o numero indicado pela ocorrência do loop
        console.log(numero + " % "+ i+ " = "+ (numero % i));
        if (calculo_numeros_primo == 0){// a cada interação se o resultado do calculo primo for igual a zero... a variável auxiliar vai receber um..se a ocorrencia do loop tiver números zero acima de 2 repetições o numero não é primo.
            auxiliar =auxiliar +1; //acrescenta 1
        }

        
        
       
    }
    if(auxiliar == 2){// fora do loop, se houve 2 repetições(considerando o primeiro divisível e o ultimo é considerado primo
        console.log( " O numero " +numero+" é primo"); //numero primo
}else{//se houver mais de 2 repetições 4 ou mais o numero indicado não é primo
    console.log( " O numero " +numero+" não é primo"); //nao é primo
}
}

entrada_numero(7);
```

Comment: Esse código eu entendo, fiz ele de começo. Apenas que naquele meu código ali eu não consigo entender é a lógica naquele código, talvez eu esteja olhando da forma errada? Sou iniciante então me desculpa qualquer burrice.

Comment: Que bom que entendeu o principio.. A ideia era criar uma função que gere os numeros e outra que responda se é ou não primo ??.... no "for" sempre inicia com o numero 1 e não pelo 2.

Comment: Depois de muito olhar, eu aprendi a debuggar e entendi meu erro xD, desculpe o incômodo e obrigado pela ajuda!